# Issue with pyarrow when loading parquet file where index has redundant column

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am using pandas/dask to do computations an I am storing my data inside a parquet file on disk. The issue is, that I have a column 'time' and also an index that is called time. I want to keep both. When I store the data and then load it later, I get the following errors:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
%matplotlib inline
dfx.to_dict()

Out[115]: 
{'close': {Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:31:00'): 154.99958999999998,
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:32:00'): 154.99958999999998,
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:33:00'): 154.01109,
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:34:00'): 154.01109,
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:35:00'): 152.60051000000001},
 'time': {Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:31:00'): Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:31:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:32:00'): Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:32:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:33:00'): Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:33:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:34:00'): Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:34:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:35:00'): Timestamp('2017-06-30 01:35:00')}}

# set index column 
dfx.set_index('time', drop=False, inplace=True)

dfx.head()
Out[117]: 
                                   time      close
time                                              
2017-06-30 01:31:00 2017-06-30 01:31:00  154.99959
2017-06-30 01:32:00 2017-06-30 01:32:00  154.99959
2017-06-30 01:33:00 2017-06-30 01:33:00  154.01109
2017-06-30 01:34:00 2017-06-30 01:34:00  154.01109
2017-06-30 01:35:00 2017-06-30 01:35:00  152.60051

# store to parquet file format
tdfx = pa.Table.from_pandas(dfx)
pq.write_table(tdfx, 'data.parquet' )


# recovering
dfx = pq.read_table('data.parquet').to_pandas()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-5e9d7cd2ea0d> in <module>()
      1 # recovering
----> 2 dfx = pq.read_table('data.parquet').to_pandas()

pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.to_pandas (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/lib.cxx:37990)()

/home/ghildebrand/anaconda3/envs/p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in table_to_blockmanager(options, table, memory_pool, nthreads)
    296         i = schema.get_field_index(name)
    297         if i != -1:
--> 298             col = table.column(i)
    299             index_name = (None if is_unnamed_index_level(name)
    300                           else name)

pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.column (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/lib.cxx:38622)()

IndexError: Table column index 2 is out of range
```

Is this a bug in pyarrow, or is this not possible with parquet or am i am doing something else wrong??

**Update**: removing the redundant column "time" and keeping only index solves. So i guess the issue is that somewhere in parquet unique sets of column identifiers are created or so.

Comment: I'd say that it should be a problem with colliding column names. Seems a bit absurd to have two times the same data for two columns, why do you need that? Just to experiment, try to do the same but remove the non index time column.

Comment: Removing the non index time column solved the issue. In deed i can rename the column, that solves the issue and is cleaner

Comment: This has been fixed in arrow master (https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/1271) and will be available in the next release, version 0.8.0.

Comment: @PhillipCloud, awesome +1 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a bit buggy to me. I opened a bug report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1754, let's continue discussing there.